# Force en-masse powerwash for 1500 chromebooks?

Tags: bash-scripting, gentoo, reset, google-chrome-os, factory-defaults

My friend refurbishes pcs, buys trucks of them from companies and reinstalls Windows, updates, etc to get them resold.I am more a linux guy than he is so he asked me if I knew a way to force the powerwash function on many chromebooks at a time. I know chrome os is a fork of gentoo, is there a way to force powerwash en-masse on many chromebooks? I was thinking maybe a script to send a signal multicast, if even possible?

**Thank you in advance for any constructive feedback! Have a great day. - Kyle**

Comment: Does he have credentials to all the Chromebooks?

Comment: That would be hugely dangerous, otherwise

Comment: It would be on a private network and he won't have credentials unfortunately. I'm not seeing an easy way, but wanted to ask.